# Using bash, how do I find all files containing a specific string and replace them with an existing file?

Tags: linux, bash, exec, xargs

I am using Linux and would like to replace all files containing the string 000000 with an existing file /home/user/offblack.png but keep the existing filename. I've been working at this for a while with various combinations of -exec and xargs but no luck. So far I have:

```
 find | grep 000000
```

Which does list all the files I want to change fine. How do I copy and replace these files with my existing offblack.png file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
find . -type f | grep 000000 | tr \\n \\0 | xargs -0i+ cp ~/offblack.png "+"
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, now reading through the man pages to understand exactly whats going on. I was not familiar with the tr command until now.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I would use:

```
find (your find args here) \
| xargs fgrep '000000' /dev/null \
| awk -F: '{print $1}' \
| xargs -n 1 -I ORIGINAL_FILENAME /bin/echo /bin/cp /path/to/offblack.png ORIGINAL_FILENAME
```

Expanding, find all the files you're interested in, grep inside of them for the string '000000' (adding /dev/null to the list of files in case one of the generated `fgrep`s ended up with only one filename - it ensures the output is always formatted as "filename: <line containing '000000'>"), strip out only the filenames, then one-by-one, copy in offblack.png over those files.  Note that I inserted a `/bin/echo` in there.  That's your dry-run.  Remove the echo to get it to run for real.

If what you mean is that the *filenames* contain "000000":

```
find . -type f -a -name '*000000*' -exec /bin/echo /bin/cp /path/to/offblack.png {} \;
```

Much simpler.  :-)  Find every file under the current directory with a name containing your string and exec the copy of offblack.png over it.  Again, what I've given you there is a dry-run.  Remove the echo for your live fire drill.  :-)

Comment: You mean "-exec /bin/cp" not "-exec /bin/echo /bin/cp", right?

Comment: As I called out in the descriptions of each of the commands in my response, those are "dry-run" versions of them; the expectation (again, mentioned alongside each command's description in my answer) is that OP would run it as-is first to see what *would* have happened, and then remove the echo when comfortable it was going to to what was wanted.  I pretty much always follow that paradigm with potentially destructive commands like this.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Let's try and use Bash a bit more:

```
for read -r filename
do
    hit=""
    for read -r
    do
        if [[ $REPLY == *000000* ]]
        then
            hit=$filename
            break
        fi
    done < $filename

    [[ -n $hit ]] && cp /path/offblack.png $filename

done < <(find . -type -f)
```

Fewer man pages to search!